# Multiple table view section: first section with static cell and second section with dynamic number of cell

Tags: uitableview, ios7

As the title says, I would like to create a table view with two sections. The first second just contains one cell with a textbox. The second section should be filled dynamically with the content of an array.

I wrote this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        Player *player = [self.playerController getPlayerAtPositon:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", player.persistentData.name];

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
       // ???
    }
}
```

But what do I have to write into the `else` codeblock? So that the cell I filld with a textbox will not be overwrite?

I found out, that you can't just add elements dynamically. When you want to add, for example, three players, you also have to set the rows-value to three. Otherwise the app will crash. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 types of cell one that has textfield, and second that has player info. So you should create a different cell identifier for each kind of cell.

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

    if(indexpath.section == 0) {
         // create and return a cell with CellIdentifier1 
    }
    else {
         // create and return a cell with CellIdentifier2  
    }
```

One more thing while allocationg UITableViewcell don't forget to add autorelease at the end ... 
Hope this will help you....

Comment: So I also can use the Cell Identifier of a static cell?

Comment: Use one identifier for cell having textfield and use different identifier for other similar cells